# Convert modis level 2 to geotiff

Tags: python

I have a file of MODIS and VIRS. Both of them are Level 2 products and i want to convert them in geotiff in python.

If it was a normal raster i would type  src_ds.GetGeoTransform() to get the relevant information. Is there any similar command to use for these files?

Comment: What extension do these files have?

Comment: The files have extension of (.nc).

Answer (score 0):

You have NetCDFs files and are probably trying to open them using `gdal` python bindings. If you want to get a GeoTIFF, one of the easiest ways is to use the [`gdal_translate` command line utility](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html). You can call it from the cmd like this:

`gdal_translate -of GTiff file.nc test.tiff`

Make sure you are either in the folder where the .nc files are or that you specify the whole path to the file in the line above. Having a TIFF then you can easily use the `.GetGeoTransform()` method.

Another way to open a .nc file using gdal is specifying it is a NetCDF file in the `gdal.Open()` function. For example you can try using the following line to open one band of the NetCDF file:

`ds = gdal.Open('NETCDF:modis_dataset.nc:band_name')`

Keep in mind that you have to know the band name. In case you want to determine the geotransform using the [`netCDF4`](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html) python package I susggest you take a look at this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261677/determine-the-geotransformation-to-convert-a-netcdf-to-geotiff